# Как выполнить https запрос используя winsock или wininet

Tags: delphi, https, winsock, wininet

Не пойму как сделать `HTTPS` запрос.

Весь интернет перерыл, нашел вот только такой код, хорошо отрабатывает `HTTP` запрос, но как только `HTTPS` то почему-то на моменте, помеченном *** выходит, в условие не заходит.

```
uses
  WinSock, WinInet

function make_request(const AUrl, AData: AnsiString; blnSSL: Boolean = True): AnsiString;
var
  aBuffer     : Array[0..4096] of Char;
  Header      : TStringStream;
  BufStream   : TMemoryStream;
  sMethod     : AnsiString;
  BytesRead   : Cardinal;
  pSession    : HINTERNET;
  pConnection : HINTERNET;
  pRequest    : HINTERNET;
  // parsedURL   : TStringArray;
  port        : Integer;
  flags       : DWord;
   scheme, host, url : string;
begin

  ParseURL(AUrl, scheme, host, url);

  Result := '';

  if (LowerCase( scheme) = 'http') then
     blnSSL := false;

  pSession := InternetOpen('MYUSERAGENT', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);

  if Assigned(pSession) then
  try
    if blnSSL or (LowerCase( scheme) = 'https') then
      Port := INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT
    else
      Port := INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
    pConnection := InternetConnect(pSession, PChar(host), port, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

    if Assigned(pConnection) then
    try
      if (AData = '') then
        sMethod := 'GET'
      else
        sMethod := 'POST';

      if blnSSL or (LowerCase( scheme) = 'https') then
        flags := INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION
      else
        flags := INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP;




      pRequest := HTTPOpenRequest(pConnection, PAnsiChar(sMethod), PAnsiChar(url), 'HTTP/1.0', nil, nil, flags, 0);

      if Assigned(pRequest) then
      try
        Header := TStringStream.Create('');
        try
          with Header do
          begin
            // 'GET '+url+' HTTP/1.1' + #13#10 +
            WriteString('GET ' + url + ' HTTP/1.1' + sLineBreak);
            WriteString('Host: ' + host + sLineBreak);
            WriteString('User-Agent: Mozila FF 55 '+SLineBreak);
            WriteString('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'+SLineBreak);
            WriteString('Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5' + SLineBreak);
            WriteString('Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'+SLineBreak);
            // WriteString('Keep-Alive: 300'+ SLineBreak);
            WriteString('Connection: close'+ SlineBreak+SLineBreak);
            // WriteString('Connection: keep-alive'+ SlineBreak+SLineBreak);
          end;

          HttpAddRequestHeaders(pRequest, PChar(Header.DataString), Length(Header.DataString), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);

          // HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil, 0, Pchar('TESTR'), Length('TESTR'));
          // *** - вот доходит до сюда и в условие не заходит
          if HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil, 0, PAnsiChar(AData), Length(AData)) then
          begin
            BufStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
            try
              while InternetReadFile(pRequest, @aBuffer, SizeOf(aBuffer), BytesRead) do
              begin
                if (BytesRead = 0) then Break;
                BufStream.Write(aBuffer, BytesRead);
              end;

              aBuffer[0] := #0;
              BufStream.Write(aBuffer, 1);
              Result := PChar(BufStream.Memory);
            finally
              BufStream.Free;
            end;
          end;
        finally
          Header.Free;
        end;
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(pRequest);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(pConnection);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(pSession);
  end;
end;
```

Нужно именно на сокетах, на компонентах любой сможет.

еще добавил обработку статуса и выяснил что выдает вот такую ошибку:

статус = 0, область данных, переданная по системному вызову, слишком мала

Comment: Так `WinInet` это уже не сокеты, а обёртка над ними, т.е. компонент. Так что определитесь с вопросом - вам про сокеты или winapi?

Comment: можно и на wininet но лучше на winapi